# How to effectively debug side effects in Python?

Tags: python, debugging, side-effects

Is there an effective way to debug side-effects in Python?

For example, list (or any different mutable object) passed as argument to function.

```
>>> some_list = [1,2]
>>> some_function_with_huge_call_tree(some_list)
>>> print some_list
[2,1]
```

How now to determine where in the program the list has been reversed?

One more example, class instance passed as argument:

```
>>> print obj.x
foo
>>> some_function_with_super_huge_call_tree(obj)
>>> print obj.x
bar
```

Where a member of the class instance has been changed?

In both cases i want something like this:

```
pdb.break_on_change(some_list)  # case 1
pdb.break_on_change(obj.x)  # case 2
```

Unfortunately, the PDB does not have such a function.

In other words, I'm trying to find a common solution for all cases.

Comment: Do you control the object that gets mutated?  If you know the function, you could let it throw an exception and inspect the stack trace.

Comment: For the list case, maybe give it a tuple and see where it fails? More generally, replace a writeable object with an identical read-only one?

Comment: Ok, list is bad example. What if argument is dict (or any different mutable type)? I try to find general solution for all cases.

Comment: What do you control?

Comment: Would it make sense for your debugging needs to adapt & use the `Tkinter`'s tracing-mechanism, seting **`.trace_variable( "w", aWriteAccessSignalHANDLER )`**? Sure, there would have to be another adaptation layer above the `{ StringVar() | DoubleVar() | IntVar() | BooleanVar() }` instances, however the need for a robust change-tracing framework may justify for such extra mile.

Answer (score 0):

You could put in a mock object that tells you what is done with it.

Here is a (too) minimal example to trace down where a mutating function attribute is called.

```
def throw(*args, **kwargs):
    raise AssertionError()

class Mock(object):

    def __init__(self, inner):
        self.__inner = inner

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'mutate':
            return throw
        return getattr(self.__inner, name)
```

Then use it as in

```
some_function(Mock(obj))
```

to find out whether `some_function` is mutating `obj`.

This example lacks many features that you would rightfully expect from a mock infrastructure.  Probably worst, it doesn't support magic.  Maybe you can expand it to fit your needs.  Actually, I would be surprised if there wouldn't already be a library that does this.